# How to improve speed of SQLite updating

Tags: java, sql, database, sqlite

I am writing a discord bot which has updates for balances of people and people get some monetary reward for each message they send.

I am using a SQLite database for this.
I tested the insertion of a large amount of entries with a queue and it ended up taking ~6.5 ms per update request with 5.5ms being spent on the update query itself and the remaining 1 ms being used to check the database if a user with the entry exists and building the query strings.

The update Queries are of the lines of: (With the top line being query)

```
  UPDATE exp12345678 SET exp = 68 , dummy = 159 WHERE userid = 54004700
  PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
   pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

And the insert query is of the line of (with the top line being the sql String).

```
INSERT INTO exp12345678(userid, exp, dummy) VALUES(?,?,?)
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                for (int i = 1; i <= args.length; i++) {
                    pstmt.setLong(i, mutationValues[i - 1]);
                }
                pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

I have attempted to use queue system with multiple threads, splitting the users among the threads based on their used id (if I use 2 Threads I would spread the user id number queries to Thread 1, while spreading the even numbered user id number queries to Thread 2). Which did not alleviate the problem.

I am not sure how I could go around solving this problem. I am using SQLite.

Further details:
The queries are done one at a time, and this is needed because if a user requests to give some value, they need to know whether their current balance is sufficient or not.

Edit: I use these SQL calls to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS exp12345678 (
 id integer PRIMARY KEY,
 userid bigint,
 exp bigint,
 dummy bigint
);
```

And these to get the values from a user (in order to create the update query).

```
SELECT * FROM exp12345678 WHERE userid = 10437023
```

Now all that I am doing is trying to add a mutation to an existing user. Is there no faster way to make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite follow your restriction for having to do one record at a time, so this may not be helpful, but executing one update at a time tends to be slow. JDBC batch inserts can have a dramatic impact on the time it takes to execute multiple queries. Below is a sample of this based on your code.

```
try (PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {

        int rowCount = 0;
        for (long mutationValue : mutationValues) {
            pstmt.setLong(i, mutationValue);
            pstmt.addBatch();
            rowCount++;
            if (rowCount % BATCH_SIZE == 0) { // You may have to do some experimentation to find a good value.
                pstmt.executeBatch();
            }
        }
        if (rowCount % BATCH_SIZE != 0) {
            pstmt.executeBatch();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Friend of me sent this minutes before you sent this, what a coincidence!
Regardless, thanks, this indeed fixed the issue, I'm getting crazy speeds right now.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if the user exists (`SELECT`) and then you are inserting (`INSERT`) it or updating it (`UPDATE`).

The `SELECT` and `UPDATE` can greatly benefit from the index:

```
create index ix1 on exp12345678 (userid);
```

Measure the times again after the index is created.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what this means?
As in, how does this line execute an update on the SQL database?

Comment: This is an index creation. You need to run it only once, not on every update. The index makes it blazing fast for SQLite to find a row when you use a condition like `WHERE userid = <number>` on SELECTs and on UPDATEs.

Comment: I executed the line as you suggested, and nothing changed. For further info I'll post the create table string and the Select string, perhaps there is some info there that explains why it didnt work.

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS exp12345678 (
 id integer PRIMARY KEY,
 userid bigint,
 exp bigint,
 dummy bigint
);

SELECT * FROM exp12345678 WHERE userid = 10437023

Comment: I edited these queries in my initial post for clarity